# Switched receptacle to fully powered receptacle withuot losing light function

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, receptacle, code-compliance

I have a bathroom receptacle that is controlled by the light switch. How do i PROPERLY separate the switch from the receptacle so as the light still works from the switch but the receptacle stays fully powered instead of shutting off when the lights go off

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light, switch, and receptacle boxes please?

Comment: Are both receptacles controlled by the switch or just one of them?   If just one it's easy peasy, if both it might not be possible without running additional cabling.

Answer (score 1):

You move the hot supplying the receptacle from the downstream connection FROM the switch to the upstream connection SUPPLYING the switch.

However the word "bathroom" should be a huge red flag here.  Do NOT touch a bathroom wiring project involving an outlet unless your intent is to replace said outlet with a GFI.  They do make GFI's with an outlet on one side and a switch on the other.

Comment: The outlet doesn’t need to be a GFCI type if GFCI protection is being supplied from elsewhere.

Comment: What @Harper-ReinstateMonica said, but the first sentence is spot on.